# Map day names array to current's week's dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been struggling to map an array of days to the dates of the current week.

This is my schema:

```
t.text "vote_frequency", default: ["wednesday"], array: true
```

The user sets one or more days of the week as vote days, and the array ends up being something like: {tuesday,wednesday,thursday,saturday}

I try to get the dates for the matching days of this week like so:

```
<% @group.vote_frequency.each do |day| %>
  <%= Date.parse(day) %>
<% end %>
```

Today is Sunday(12th), but the Monday shows up as Monday(13th), Tuesday(14th), etc... which are days for the next week, not this week.

What's the best way to approach this?
I'm using Rails 7.

I initially thought it had something to do with the week start date and added `config.beginning_of_week = :monday` to my `application.rb`, but it didn't help.

Comment: You need to provide DATE a given week starts on -- without that context the code has no way to decide which date to map a given date to. PS. Generating a calendar table makes this kind of date work much easier -- always surer to lookup than calculate.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand our requirements. Do you always return the weekday of the previous week? Or of the current week, that you define going from Monday to Sunday? What if the current weekday is a Wednesday and the input is Friday? Do you expect to return the last Friday from the previous week or the next Friday from this week?

Comment: Sorry @spickermann. I could have been clearer. "I try to get the dates for the matching days of *this* week like so:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `#prev_day` method to workaround the issue:

```rb
days = Date.today.wday == 0 ? 7 : 0

@group.vote_frequency.each do |day|
  Date.parse(day).prev_day days
end
```

Comment: This is what I was after. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What's about combine [`prev_occurring`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-prev_occurring) and [`next_occuring`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-next_occurring)?

```rb
previous_sunday = Time.now.to_date.prev_occurring(:sunday)

@group.vote_frequency.map { |day| previous_sunday.next_occurring(day.to_sym) }
```

Firstly we get previous week Sunday

And after that map through `vote_frequency` array and convert all string days to current week dates

For example

```rb
previous_sunday = '2023-03-12'.to_date.prev_occurring(:sunday)
# => Sun, 05 Mar 2023

%w[monday tuesday sunday].map { |day| previous_sunday.next_occurring(day.to_sym) }
# => [Mon, 06 Mar 2023, Tue, 07 Mar 2023, Sun, 12 Mar 2023]
```

Since you have such array, you can render it in the view in required format